# Does the sequence converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble understanding how to do this one. If anyone could help I would be grateful.
Does the sequence 
        $$  \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^k \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+n}} \right) \right\}_{k=1}^\infty $$
        diverge or converge?  If the sequence converges, find the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For large $k$,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+n}} \approx \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2}} = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{k} = 1. $$